# TouchableHighlight won't accept press events while keyboard is open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component which contains a TextInput and a TouchableHighlight side by side. You tap on the textbox, type what you want, then tap the add button to save it. Now the problem is the keyboard open from typing, you need to dismiss it, otherwise the button won't respond. If i tap the button first, the keyboard dismissed, then a second tap works. I feel like i should able to do both in one.  Here's my render component:

```
class FormInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: null
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.textInput.focus();
  }

  _changeTextEvent(event) {
    this.setState({
      text: event.nativeEvent.text
    });
  }

  render() {
    var style = [styles.textBox];
    if (this.props.errors.length > 0) {
      style.push(styles.errorTextBox);
    }
    var errors = null;
    if (this.props.errors.length > 0) {
      errors = this.props.errors.map((msg) => {
        return (<Text style={styles.errorLabel}>{msg}</Text>);
      });
    }
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TextInput
            ref='textInput'
            style={style}
            onChange={this._changeTextEvent.bind(this)}
            autoFocus={true}
          />
          <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="#96DBFF" style={styles.addButton} onPress={() => { this.props.pressEvent(this.state.text) }}>
            <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>Add</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <View>{errors}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'll update if I find a fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see this discussion on calling `blur` on a textfield to dismiss it:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/113

Also, I just tested this on the simulator and the TouchableHighlight definitely does respond even when the TextInput has focus and the keyboard is up. By adding code like:

```
pressEvent() {
    this.refs.textInput.blur();
}
```

I am able to dismiss the keyboard from the TouchableHighlight.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I adjusted my TouchableHighlight onPress event to use a method on the component: `_pressEvent() {
    this.refs.textInput.blur();
    this.props.pressEvent(this.state.text);
  }`  But it does not work. If i drop a breakpoint on the method here, it does not fire until after the keyboard dismisses. Could something else be capturing the event?

Comment: This component is rendered inside a ScrollView. On the scrollview docs it does say "Doesn't yet support other contained responders from blocking this scroll view from becoming the responder."

Comment: Yeah i moved the form component outside of the scroll view, button responds now.

Comment: ScrollView has an option for that now called `keyboardshouldpersisttaps`, check http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboardshouldpersisttaps